# How to get the value from Marshal in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I have a following lines of code:

```
public static string getTrack1(string track1, int len)
{
  IntPtr track1Ptr = UnsafeNativeMethods.Decrypt(track1, len);
  Byte[] track1b = new Byte[200];
  Marshal.Copy(track1Ptr, track1b, 0, track1b.Length);
   return track1b.ToString();
}
```

deceleration of decrypt method is :

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
  [DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern IntPtr Decrypt(string track1, int dataLen);
 }
```

I am returning `unsigned char*` from `visual c++` code and whenever i am calling the dll from `c#` code it always returns "`System.Byte[]`" instead of value. Am i doing something wrong here in `marshal`?

please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the transformation from byte[] to string, but you'll have to define what's the encoding. This may work:

```
public static string getTrack1(string track1, int len)
{
  IntPtr track1Ptr = UnsafeNativeMethods.Decrypt(track1, len);
  Byte[] track1b = new Byte[200];
  Marshal.Copy(track1Ptr, track1b, 0, track1b.Length);
   return Encoding.Default.GetString(track1b);
}
```

But it would be better to do this;

```
public static string getTrack1(string track1, int len)
{
  IntPtr track1Ptr = UnsafeNativeMethods.Decrypt(track1, len);
  return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(track1Ptr);
}
```

If the encoding is Ansi (=Default)

Answer (score 1):

`Byte[].ToString()` method always returns `System.Byte[]`.

To convert byte array to its string representation you must do something like this:

```
public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] source)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(source.Length * 3);

    foreach (byte b in source)
    {
        builder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
        builder.Append(' ');
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```